# UML Assignment Doubts

Tags: uml

I have a small UML assignment due Monday; it doesn't seem too complicated, and I'm not asking this site to solve it for me -- I'm just asking for clarification over a couple doubts of mine.

I'm just telling parts of the assignment because its content is probably not so relevant.

We're provided a basic use case where the actors "officer" (e.g. police officer) communicates with the actor "correspondent" in order to report an emergency. The use case is expressed in the form:

> Use case name: Report emergency
>
> Participating actors: Officer, correspondent
>
> Flow of events: ...
>
> Preconditions: ...
>
> Postconditions: ...

Then we're given three scenarios that "refine" the use case. I say "refine" because they turn it upside-down: they involve team leaders, respondents, incident handling -- nothing that was even mentioned in the flow of events described by the very basic use case given.

On top of these scenarios we're given ten "events" (i.e. they basically chunk the three scenarios into ten easily recognizable sentences). The assignment asks us to make one collaboration diagram for each of these events.

I know that collaboration diagrams describe the behaviour of the system, i.e. how the different parts of the systems interact with each other. So I thought that, even with these "creative" scenarios given, I could make something out of them. But then this part comes:

"Collaboration diagrams should make use of controller, boundary, domain objects and other new fabricated software objects (e.g. data structure components) necessary to completely handle each event."

And then:

"Your assignment will be evaluated in terms of the quality of your design (i.e. modularity: low coupling, high cohesion)"

My questions are:

1) Are scenarios supposed to present so much new information compared to the basic use case?

2) Do I just have to draw ten simple collaboration diagrams? Using which classes?

3) Why are things like low coupling, high cohesion, domain objects, mentioned? What do they have to do with all of this?

Answer (score 0):

1) A scenario is a detailed description of a use case. There can be several scenarios based on constraints. The use case itself just describes the sunny day scenario in a condensed format. The meat is in the scenarios.

2) Classes related to the UC can be extracted when going through the scenario. You will find text parts that tell certain functions need to be performed. Take these classes and place them in the collaboration diagram and connect them with the right message.

3) These are general design rules. Low coupling/high cohesion means good design (and vice versa).  The domain objects are those which are in the center of the system and the sum of all use cases will deal with the sum of all domain objects.